# Install profile

Tags: 7, distributions

I'm creating a Drupal installation profile and transfering taxonomy vocabularies through features, like this:

**my_profile.info:**

; Features

...

dependencies[] = my_profile_taxonomy_vocabularies

...

These vocabularies are created correctly, but I also should automatically create terms. If I put my function which creates terms into **my_profile_install()**, it's not working. At this moment, vocabularies are not available. Also I've tried to use direct SQL query and vocabularies are not created at this moment.

Where can I put my code for terms creation, when vocabularies are already created and available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a install task in .profile, install tasks are run after modules are enabled.

Here's an example you can use as a starting point:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_install_tasks().
 */
function PROFILE_install_tasks() {
  $tasks = array(
    'create_taxonomy_terms' => array(
      'display_name' => st('Create taxonomy terms'),
      'type' => 'normal', // the default
    ),
  );
  return $tasks;
}

/**
 * Install task: Create taxonomy terms.
 */
function PROFILE_create_taxonomy_terms() {
  // your stuff.
}
```

The install task is declared as normal, that means the related function will be executed. If you're going to create a lot of terms, better write a batch. See the  api docs for reference:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/7

Comment: Thank you! It's works for me! And yes I need batch for my functionallity.